# How do I convert int to int8_t?

Tags: casting, type-conversion, d, dmd

How do I convert `int` to `int8_t?` `cast()` / `to!int8_t()` didn't work.

```
const nblocks = l /4;
const int8_t i = to!int8_t(nblocks) * 4;
```

compile-error:

> Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (cast(int)to(nblocks) * 4)
>   of type int to const(byte)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int8_t` is a typedef in C/C++ to the `signed char` (8 bits, signed integer). This type corresponds to the `byte` in D, so `to!byte(nblocks)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use C's stdint, the module `std.stdint` present in Phobos provides proper aliases.

Documentation: http://dlang.org/phobos/std_stdint.html

Edit: the original problem in your code is the multiplication by four in the last line. When you are multiplying a `byte`/`int8_t` by four, the value may not fit in a byte. If you are sure you want to have the value in a byte, then you either use a checked conversion to `byte`/`int8_t` using `to` for the total result, or use an unchecked `cast`.

```
const int8_t i = (nblocks * 4).to!int8_t;
```

Comment: It's the one I was using and caused the error. I wasn't looking exactly for the C's one but a data type with same size. So I found that.

Comment: When I reread my answer, I realised I didn't answer your question. I have updated my answer explaining what went wrong with your example. So `byte` or `int8_t` should have the same problem anyway.